# Unwrapping Optional Play Route Parameters In Comprehensions

Tags: scala, functional-programming, playframework-2.0, future, for-comprehension

I have the following pattern:

1. Some play route with some optional parameters defined

> GET /my/route                controllers.something.Class.method(maybeA: Optional[Int], maybeB: Optional[Int])

In the method, I'd like to be able to use those parameters. I feel like I don't understand the proper pattern to use. What I'd like to do is something like:

```
blah match {
    case Some(someCase) => // do something
    case _ => for {
        a <- maybeA
        b <- maybeB
    } yield {
        somethingThatReturnsAFuture(a, b)
    }
}
```

The problem is that the for comprehension returns an `Option[Future[Int]]`, but I need it to return `Future[Int]`. I'd like to be able to just throw a `get` on the end of the comprehension, but that smells funny (and I don't actually think it's possible to just throw `get` at the end of the comprehension).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If something is `Option` then the result of the direct processing of this will be `Option` as well. The only way to get rid of `Option` is to define the `None` case.

```
val resultOpt: Option[Future[Int]] = blah match { ...
val result: Future[Int] = resultOpt match {
  case Some(f) => f
  case None => Future.successful(0)
}
```

Or just use `getOrElse`. The same code, different style:

```
val resultOpt: Option[Future[Int]] = blah match { ...
val result: Future[Int] = resultOpt.getOrElse(Future.successful(0))
```

A little bit more about this:
http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-multiple-options-for-loop-comprehension